# How can I insert the price per category in wordpress using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am doing a project that inserts a csv file to the wordpress database and creates the products based on the data. I have so far been able to insert the fields with no problem, except when it comes to variation product.

I know that this can be achieved with the php meta data it generates but I am trying to figure this out just doing it via MySQL.

I created a test product with a variable attributes of size and price. I get the following (not linking wp_post table since it only link the product with the name od the product):

wp_postmeta:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value

'50830', '12681', '_stock', NULL
'50831', '12681', '_stock_status', 'instock'
'50832', '12681', '_product_attributes', 'a:1:{s:7:\"pa_size\";a:6:{s:4:\"name\";s:7:\"pa_size\";s:5:\"value\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"position\";i:1;s:10:\"is_visible\";i:1;s:12:\"is_variation\";i:1;s:11:\"is_taxonomy\";i:1;}}'
'51150', '12681', 'wc_productdata_options', 'a:1:{i:0;a:9:{s:11:\"_bubble_new\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"_bubble_text\";s:0:\"\";s:17:\"_custom_tab_title\";s:0:\"\";s:11:\"_custom_tab\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"_product_video\";s:0:\"\";s:19:\"_product_video_size\";s:0:\"\";s:24:\"_product_video_placement\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"_top_content\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"_bottom_content\";s:0:\"\";}}'
'51349', '12681', '_price', '10'
'51350', '12681', '_price', '15'
'51351', '12681', '_price', '20'
'51352', '12681', '_regular_price', ''
'51353', '12681', '_sale_price', ''
```

wp_term_relationships:

```
object_id | term_taxonomy_id | term_order

'12681', '4', '0'
'12681', '19', '0'
'12681', '20', '0'
'12681', '21', '0'
'12681', '22', '0'
'12681', '189', '0'
'12681', '196', '0'
'12681', '204', '0'
'12681', '218', '0'
'12681', '219', '0'
```

wp_term_taxonomy:

```
term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy | description | parent | count

'4','4','product_type','','0','1'
'19','19','pa_size','','0','1'
'20','20','pa_size','','0','1'
'21','21','pa_size','','0','1'
'22','22','pa_size','','0','1'
'189','189','pa_size','','0','1'
'196','196','pa_size','','0','1'
'204','225','product_cat','','0','1'
'218','217','pa_size','','0','1'
'219','219','pa_size','','0','1'
```

wp_term:

```
term_id | name | slug | term_group
'4','variable','variable','0'
'19','XS','xs','0'
'20','S','s','0'
'21','M','m','0'
'22','L','l','0'
'189','3XL','3xl','0'
'196','4XL','4xl','0'
'217','XL','XL','0'
'219','XXL','XXL','0'
'225','Shirt','shirt','0'
```

wp_term_meta:

```
meta_id | term_id | meta_key | meta_value
'103','189','order_pa_size','0'
'110','196','order_pa_size','0'
'121','225','order','0'
'122','225','display_type',''
'123','225','thumbnail_id','0'
'178','225','product_count_product_cat','1'
```

I notice that it links the price with the size in wp_term_meta using meta_id and term_id.

So my questions would be:

What does the meta_key represent?
How can I assign the size with the corresponding price to? 
Is there a way to do this using SQL or would I have to incorporate some type of php code?

Comment: Found a related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034862/how-to-get-product-attributes-from-wordpress-database

Comment: To my luck the answer is within wp_postmeta under _product_attributes. How this works PHP collects all the SQL data first then it insert the serialized data. This is my serialize data that was used on all my products.     a:1:{s:7:"pa_size";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:7:"pa_size";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:8:"position";i:1;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:1;}}

Comment: WP_options is stored using meta to assign each field with meta_id in wp_post.postmeta